# Smart Date Key Vs Date Data Type in Date Dimension Table

Tags: sql-server, database

I'm currently designing a database and will employ a Date Dimension table that will contain the various possible groupings a user may wish to report on e.g. financial year, quarter etc. This will be role played through views to create versions for Order Date, Cancellation Date etc and then merged with other Dimension tables.

Common database design theory advocates a smart key of form YYYYMMDD that is used to merge with other tables, however, I wonder if this is still valid. My understanding is that SQL Server, which is what I'm using, uses a data type of Date which is three bits over an integer of 4 bits.

Assuming that I do not require records that would identify records where date is "Unknown"or "Not Available" etc, is there any reason to use an integer smart key over date?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: Why would a date ever be the only way you could identify a row where the date itself was not known or not available? This doesn't sound to me like a "key" at all. If you don't know a patient's birthdate or the policy renewal date or the license expiration, you put NULL there, not an integer like `00000009`. In relational databases we're allowed to have NULL and outer joins; don't sacrifice all the things you get by using the right data type to optimize for data warehouse thinking (if you really need to normalize / de-NULL in the reporting side of things, you can do that there). IMHO.

Comment: You say you have dimension tables but what do you mean by "merged"? Do you just mean "joined"? Also see [using a calendar table](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/) - there are some comments there too about integer vs. date.